# Sending Pictures to Firebase Android

Tags: android, image, firebase, base64

In my app the user can add a picture to the post. I want the picture to be sent to Firebase in a String format so it can be accessed by all users viewing the post. I already have it so the camera is opened and the picture is saved and is given a unique name. My issue lies in converting the image to a base64 String.

This is how I have it set up to take the pictures and save them. the String date is for the unique file name.

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----


            File image = new File(imagesFolder, date + ".jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);
```

Comment: Firebase just launched a new [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) feature, which means you don't have to base64 encode image data anymore. I highly recommend that you check that out, instead of continuing on this path, that has lead to painful experiences for almost anyone who tried.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem lies in converting your image (which is actually a `Bitmap` image when your `onActivityResult()` returns something), there is an easy way to do that. First, you will have to convert your `Bitmap` to a byte array. You can do that like this:

```
// Retrieve your Bitmap here
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); // 'bitmap' is the image returned
byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
```

Then to convert the byte array, just use the Android class provided:

```
String b64Image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

You could then upload that specific `String` to Firebase with your method, but here is an example:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child("image").setValue(b64Image);
```

This should properly save your encoded Base64 `String` to Firebase. Hope it helps!